# Context is clearing on page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-hooks

I am currently building a react app and am in the beginning stages of setting up my user authentication. The actual user management is pretty easy, as I am using a database service (Supabase) that handles all the user authentication / session management for me. However, I have run into an issue with conditionally rendering parts of my app based on whether or not the user is signed in. For example, I am wanting to render a different navigation bar with different buttons based on if there is a user signed in or not. I have created a custom hook to hold all the sign in stuff from supabase and am attempting to create a context that I can reference elsewhere in the app. My context seems to be giving me trouble though. When I initially log in with a valid user, everything works as expected. I can see the user ID in the context store, and my navigation bar renders according to a logged in user. However, I have found that if I reload the page, my context value clears. Here is the code where I am initializing my context (please note my use of typescript):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import useCurrentUser from "../hooks/useCurrentUser";
import supabase from "../supabaseClient";

type TestT = [String, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<String>>];

const UserContext = createContext<TestT>(undefined!);

export function useUser() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function UserProvider({ children }: any) {
  console.log("IN USER PROVIDER");
  console.log(useCurrentUser());
  const [test, setTest] = useState(useCurrentUser()!);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[test, setTest]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { UserContext };
```

So here is the problem. You will notice I am setting the value in the Provider to a state value, which is defaulting to my useCurrentUser hook. However, when I reload the page, I can see in react dev tools that the 'test' state, and therefore the Provider value, are being set to undefined. This is perplexing, because just prior to setting the 'test' state value to the useCurrentUser hook value, I am printing it, and it does in fact print a valid user ID. So, I am confused why, even though useCurrentUser DOES have a value, it is not setting to my state value and provider value. What am I doing wrong here? How can I get my context to retain the user ID even when the page reloads?

Comment: save your user information in localstorage or things like cookie, etc.?

Comment: can only assume that initially `useCurrentUser()` returns undefined (i.e. on the first render) and the receives a value on a subsequent render, by this time the `useState` would have already set `test` to the initial value of `undefined` and will no longer care about what is returned by `useCurrentUser()`. Maybe this could be fixed by doing `const user = useCurrentUser(); useEffect(() => { setTest(user); }, [user, setTest]);`

Comment: That you, @JacobSmit!! The useEffect did the trick.